# What would be the best way to select and display featured entries?

Tags: entries, best-practice

What would be the best way to select and display featured entries? For example, if I want to choose at least 3 entries to feature in a sidebar apart from the main content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a custom [category](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/categories) OR a lightswitch field like it's described in the [documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/lightswitch-fields).

Personally I would go with a category since you can fetch the entries for that particular category directly. With a lightswtich (I think) you need to fetch all, then run a if-statement to see which is selected.

Comment: You can fetch entries with lightswitch on like so: `craft.entries.myLightSwitchName('1').find()`. One advantage of the category solution though: you could add subcategories and other more complex stuff. For a simple solution (UX wise) I'd go with a lighswitch.

Answer (score 2):

It always depends on your needs, so there is not really a best way to do feature entries, at least if you don't give more specific info on what your exact situation is.

To have a nice overview of which entries are featured, you could add a new section (structure or channel), with an [entries field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/entries-fields) to collect the entries you want to be featured.

Another idea would be to collect the feature entries in a global set using matrix. You need just a single block type, again with an [entries field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/entries-fields) to make the relations.

A Matrix field or a structure section enables you to (optionally) re-order the entries to your liking.